# why is select_dtypes so slow

Tags: performance, pandas

Why is select_dtypes so slow?

```
%timeit [col for col in df.columns if np.issubdtype(df[col].dtype, np.number)]
```

453 microsecs per loop

```
%timeit df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
```

4.58 secs per loop

Comment: I'd post an issue on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) as this seems to be really inefficient, I get 1.59ms vs 45.7 us when comparing select_dtypes vs list comprehension

Comment: AFAIK, the idea behind `select_dtypes()` is to select a subset of DF (not subset of columns), so it returns data (all rows), which of course takes time...

Comment: Why does that have to take time? It does not have to actually move any data just return pointers to columns.