# Efficiently Return Numeric Column Names from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe in Python (3.6) with numeric and categorical attributes. I want to **pull a list of numeric columns** for use in other parts of my code. My question is what is the most efficient way of doing this?

[This seems to be the standard answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898414/find-numeric-column-names-in-pandas):

```
num_cols = df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns.tolist()
```

But I'm worried that `select_dtypes()` [can be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427864/why-is-select-dtypes-so-slow) and this seem to add a middle step that I'm hoping isn't necessary (subsetting the data before pulling back the column names of just the numeric attributes).

Any ideas on a more efficient way of doing this? (I know there is a private method `_get_numeric_data()` that could also be used, but wasn't able to find out how that works and I don't love using a private method as a long-term solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.select_dtypes` is for selecting data, it **makes a copy of your data**, which you essentially discard, by then only selecting the columns. This *is* an inefficent way. Just use something like:

```
df.columns[[np.issubdtype(dt, np.number) for dt in df.dtypes]]
```

Comment: I wrapped this in list() to return it as a list, but essentially this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! And thanks for confirming that select_dtypes is inefficient. It didn't make sense to me that that would be the best way to get JUST the column names, which is what I was after.

Comment: actually it doesn't generally copy; this is only a view; it is exactly like subsetting the columns themselves

Comment: @Jeff it was my impression that it is generally hard to predict whether this returns a view or a copy, and it depends on the memory layout of the underlying array. I suspect, though, if you have mixed numeric dtypes, it almost certainly will return a copy rather than a view.

Comment: no this will almost always return a view; data is already stored dtype segregated; the memory layout is not relevant here; when you subset memory layout comes into play

Comment: @Jeff um, I just tested this out with [the example from the docs](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/3413004317b2826842412d69e88c3e29), and it returns a copy, not a view, or is there something I am fundamentally misunderstanding?

Comment: it shouldn't ; could be a bug in that it does actually invoke copy (it's not a view directly)

Comment: @Jeff Well, looking at the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L2188-L2303) it returns `self.loc[com._get_info_slice(self, dtype_indexer)]`, and there isn't any obvious place where an explicit copy is being made, although some stuff is hidden behind [helper-functions](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/common.py#L148), but again, nothing obvious as far as I can tell. Are you saying since only the columns are subset, then it should reliably return a view?

Comment: yes; these grab whole blocks by dtype so they get returned directly; how exactly are you testing whether it's an actual copy? this is actually non trivial with mixed dtypes

Comment: @Jeff [here's a dump from an IPython session](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/3413004317b2826842412d69e88c3e29)

Comment: you are misunderstanding; that actually indicates u have a view into the original frame; this is certainly a view here; look at df.c.values.base (same as original frame);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155365/discussion-between-juanpa-arrivillaga-and-jeff).

Comment: @Jeff, eh, if it were a *view*, then would't the changes in `sub` be reflected in `df`? Like if I did `b = df.loc[:,'b']` then `b.iloc[0,0] = False` I should see `False` in `df.loc[0, 'b']`

Comment: sure for some dtypes (boolean is not one of them); but floats sure

Comment: @Jeff what? My point is that there is a `999.99` in `sub`, which is the object returned by `df. select_dtypes`, but none in `df`, so `sub` cannot be a view. What am I not getting? Indeed, for that `bool` column, I did see the view behavior when I do `b = df.loc[:,'b']`

Comment: .loc can create a copy,[] generally will not; this is why view semantics are tricky; .loc[:, ] is a filter even though it doesn't look like one

Comment: @Jeff well, exactly. My point is, `sub` in the example I gave *shows copy behavior*.

Comment: well pls file an issue then; this should be a view

Answer (score 0):

Two ways (without using df.select_dtypes which unnecessarily creates a temporary intermediate dataframe):

```
import numpy as np
[c for c in df.columns if np.issubdtype(df[c].dtype, np.number)]
```

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
[c for c in df.columns if is_numeric_dtype(c)]
```

Or if you want the result to be a pd.Index rather than just a list of column name strings as above, here are three ways (first is from @juanpa.arrivillaga):

```
import numpy as np
df.columns[[np.issubdtype(dt, np.number) for dt in df.dtypes]]
```

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
df.columns[[is_numeric_dtype(c) for c in df.columns]]
```

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
df.columns[list(map(is_numeric_dtype, df.columns))]
```

Some other solutions consider a bool column to be numeric, but the solutions above do not (tested with numpy 1.22.3 / pandas 1.4.2).